# Want to create make ,model and year type work in Open cart

Tags: filter, attributes, opencart, opencart-module

I want to create `Make,model and year` type work in open cart.I am new to `open cart` and don't know which one suite my work.Since model depends on make and similarly year depends on model value.So keeping in mind that i am unable to select which one i select for my work.Hopefully someone get my point.this type of work done in extensions but i want to do it by my own.So want to know filter will be best or attributes for this kind of work.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of affordable options in the opencart extension store as well as codecanyon

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3621

is the one I use, love it. Developing this for yourself will be a ton of work and likely be buggy if you're asking for help here. There are many variables to consider, which is why I always advise you purchase a tested and true extension.